# Positioning of a menu, menu items automatic among each other separated in two rows

Tags: html, css

For a mobile website I need a construction to get the result as below.
[image: Menu]
We working with a CMS, so I've got some auto-generated HTML.

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="#">Main item 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Main item 2</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Main item 3</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

To make items floated or display inline-block doesn't solve the issue.

Is it possible to do that with this HTML, or do I create two columns and spread the menu items to each column?

I've created a CodePen: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVNReo)

Comment: do you have any css?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a masonry library if you want it to line up as space-efficiently as possible.

Here's an example library:
https://github.com/desandro/masonry